# How to check link to correctly filling in SFSafariViewController?

Tags: swift

I use SFSafariViewController to present Safari from UIView. Link gets from the user.
My code:

```
@IBAction func linkTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let urlString = record?.link else { return }
        if urlString != "" {
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url!)
            vc.delegate = self
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

If `urlString` is https://stackoverflow.com everything works nice, but if it's like stackoverflow.com app crashes. How to check the link to correctly filling? And how to transform link if a user did it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work without the http. Just remind users to put it in before the link

Comment: How can I check http exist or not? if not,  don't execute method at all